# "Пропустить" клавишу на вводе текста с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html

задача следующая: при вводе текста в input нужно запретить вводить определенные символы с клавиатуры. пробовал так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>func key</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="inner">
    <p id="outer"></p>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
        var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
        inner.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
            // 79 - > ето буква 'O'
            if(event.charCode == 79) return false;
            console.log('hello');
            console.log('char code = '+event.charCode);
            console.log('key code = '+event.keyCode);
        })
    });
</script>
</html>
```

в данном случае хочу запретить вводить кнопку "o", возвращаю false, а событие все равно происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста как могу это реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  var disabledChars = ['o'];
  
  $('#inner').on('keypress', function(e){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // Введённый символ
    
    if(disabledChars.indexOf(char) !== -1) return false; // Если в массиве disabledChars есть введённый символ, то ничего не произойдёт
    
    console.info('Char: ' + char);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inner" autofocus />
```

Comment: +1 ). C jQuery познакомился неделю назад. Читать такие ответы приятно.

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin, А я с ней вообще не знаком, только пару функций знаю :)
Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: спасибо за нативный джаваскрипт ответ, помогли

Comment: @IgorKalamurda, Это не нативный JS, а библиотека jQuery, поскольку в коде используется именно она.
Хотя в нативном особо и не отличается.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю если уж подключил JQuery, то можно так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#inner').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 79) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inner">
<p id="outer"></p>
```

вместо

```
$(function(){
    var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
    var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
    inner.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
        // 79 - > ето буква 'O'
        if(event.charCode == 79) return false;
        console.log('hello');
        console.log('char code = '+event.charCode);
        console.log('key code = '+event.keyCode);
    })
});
```

Comment: @romeo, красиво форматируете, спасибо ). Никак не могу найти времени, чтобы разобраться с форматированием отчетов.

Comment: Vasil Baymurzin, да не за что :) Там всё просто.

Comment: Заметьте, вариант с `e.which == 79` не различает заглавную и строчную О, и запрещает вводить обе.

Comment: из джей квери хороший пример, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

`return false;` в обработчике работает только если обработчик был назначен через `on`:

```
inner.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (...) return false;
};
```

При добавлении обработчика через `addEventListener` отменять событие нужно при помощи [`preventDefault()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp):

```
if (e.charCode === 79) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8m73xsb6/1/

Обратите внимание на код [этого](https://github.com/northern/Input-Filter-JS/blob/dev-master/jquery-input-filter.js) плагина к jQuery, там учитывается в том числе и вставка текста из буфера обмена.